# How to get counts among tree-structured records with a single SQL query

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

```
Master table: top
Fields: id, field1

Details table: middle
Fields: id, top_id, category, selection
The category field can only have two values: red, blue.
The selection field only has two values: good, bad
This table has a reference field (top_id) pointing to the top table

Extra table: bottom
Fields id, middle_id, value (value field can only have values 1, 2)
This table has a reference field (middle_id) only pointing to the records in the middle table whose category value is "red".
```

Now I hope to get counts of "good" or "bad" values of "blue" records in the middle table over the values of the "value" field in the bottom table when

```
1. there are "red" records in the middle table, AND
2. these "red" records point to the same records in the top table as the "blue" records, AND
3. these "red" records have details records in the bottom table and these records have 1 or 2 or 3 in the "value" field.
```

Visually, these records form a tree structure as follows:

```
top (top table)-----records in the middle table with category being "blue"
                |
                |----records in the middle table with category being "red"
                     |
                     |-------records in the bottom table
```

In my situation, I cannot use database-specific solutions or procedures. I HOPE to write a single query for this, but failed to do so.

**UPDATE**

The target results should be rows similar to the following:

1 (the value of the bottom "value" field), good ("blue" records with "good" value), 3 ("good" value of "blue" records appears three times for value "1")

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE 2**

I believe Misandrist's answer is the right, but he probably wrote it very quickly. After my test, I made changes and the following is the complete working script.

```
SELECT bottom.value, mblue.selection, COUNT(mblue.id)
FROM TOP
INNER JOIN middle AS mred ON mred.top_id = top.id
INNER JOIN bottom ON bottom.middle_id = mred.id
INNER JOIN middle AS mblue ON mblue.top_id = top.id
WHERE mred.category = 'red'
AND mblue.category = 'blue'
AND bottom.value in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY bottom.value, mblue.selection
```

Misandrist, thank you!

Comment: What *flavor* of SQL are you using? What have you already tried?

Comment: PM 77-1, thanks for the right question. While you asked, I updated my question. I am hoping to have a database-independent non-procedure query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's come up with the query that describes the relations:

```
SELECT * FROM top
INNER JOIN middle AS mblue ON mblue.top_id = top.id
INNER JOIN bottom ON bottom.middle_id = mblue.id
```

Since we have multiple constraints for the middle table, we'll add another join for it:

```
INNER JOIN middle AS mred ON mred.top_id = top.id
```

Next, let's express the constraints:

there are "red" records in the middle table:

```
WHERE mred.category = red
```

AND these "red" records point to the same records in the top table as the "blue" records:

```
AND mblue.category = blue
```

AND these "red" records have details records in the bottom table and these records have 1 or 2 or 3 in the "value" field:

```
AND bottom.value in (1, 2, 3)
```

Put it all together:

```
SELECT * 
FROM top
INNER JOIN middle AS mred ON mred.top_id = top.id
INNER JOIN bottom ON bottom.middle_id = mblue.id
INNER JOIN middle AS mblue ON mblue.top_id = top.id
WHERE mred.category = 'red'
AND mblue.category = 'blue'
AND bottom.value in (1, 2, 3)
```

These describe the shape of the constraints.

Now lets get the counts of "good" or "bad" values of "blue" records in the middle table over the values of the "value" field in the bottom table:

```
SELECT bottom.value, mblue.selection, COUNT(mblue.id)
INNER JOIN middle AS mred ON m1.top_id = top.id
INNER JOIN bottom ON bottom.middle_id = mblue.id
INNER JOIN middle AS mblue ON mblue.top_id = top.id
WHERE mred.category = 'red'
AND mblue.category = 'blue'
AND bottom.value in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY bottom.value, mblue.selection
```

Note that the core structure of the query stayed the same, but we just replaced the `SELECT`, and added a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Misandrist, thanks so much for your step-by-step approach to solving this complex query problem. I am hoping to see the results similar to : 1 (the value of the bottom "value" field), good ("blue" records with "good" value), 3 ("good" value of "blue" records appears three times for value "1"). I am unable to see such as results in your query. I hope my post is clear enough. If not, sorry for my poor English. Regards.

Comment: Misandrist, thank you soooooooooooooo much for response and quick update for such a complex query. I am amazed by your SQL code capability. I am going to digest what you provided carefully Again, thanks!!!

Comment: Misandrist, I am unable to see "FROM" in your query for "SELECT". Besides, you have "m1" alias. Not able to run your code. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't "INNER JOIN bottom ON bottom.middle_id = mblue.id" be changed to "INNER JOIN bottom ON bottom.middle_id = mred.id"?

Comment: Misandrist, if my observations are right, could you please update your post from beginning? I hope to leave others a correct and brilliant answer. It seems your query works correctly, but I would like to hear your thoughts about my comments. Regards.

Comment: I've corrected the errors, and redid a bit of the text. Also I made the `FROM` clause a bit more clear I hope.